# Custom views preventing swiping in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager` that is connected to `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`.

Now each fragment from that `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` that comes to `ViewPager` is made up of custom views.

Problem is, if I start swiping on those custom views, `ViewPager` won't react to swipe, but I have to carefully position my finger between those custom views and then swipe so it `catches` the swiping motion.

Anyone knows what is the problem? I tried setting those custom views to `android:clickable="true"` and `android:clickable="false"` but it didn't work.

Comment: Does your custom `View` have an `onTouchListener`?

Comment: My custom View doesn't have an onTouchListener.

Comment: You can use `android:focusble="true"` or `android:enable="true"`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

in the constructors of your custom views, use `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);`

Also, if your custom view contains a textview, then make sure you replace `android:singleLine="true"` with `android:maxLines="1"` otherwise it breaks the viewpager horizontal scrolling ! (Gotta love Google's lovely bugs!)

Answer (score -2):

add this line to your custom view

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: didn't work; swiping on the custom view inside the viewpager did not start the horizontal swiping